# How can I show the "content" menu without the "Access the Content overview page" permission?

Tags: 9, navigation

On a site, I installed the Media and [Microcontent](https://www.drupal.org/project/microcontent) modules. I need to set up two user roles, one which should access only the "Media content overview" page and the other one which should access only the "Micro-content overview" page.

I've seen both modules share a similar behavior, as they place their overview page route under the `system.admin_content` link.

From my test, if the roles don't have the *Access the Content overview page permission, they can't view the menu link on the Administration menu, even if they can access the relative page (/admin/content/media).

If they have that permission, they can see the menu, but they can also access to the *Node overview* (admin/structure/views/view/content) view and see the relative link in the menu, which should not be possible for them.

I've also tried to give them that permission and change the content view (admin/structure/views/view/content) permission to one those roles haven't.
However, even with this configuration setup the roles, can't see the menu.

Is there a way to make this work?